# How to negate \forall?

Tags: symbols

In one of the slides at my university the negation of \forall was used. It looked like this:
[image]

I want to use the symbol, so I searched for it using [this StackExchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character?newreg=c3226803691942a5962380390733d639), but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Is it even used? If yes, what's the LaTeX command?

Comment: You'd say that there exists an x for which not F.

Comment: I've never seen it. You may do `\usepackage{centernot}` and `\centernot{\forall}`.

Comment: From a purely mathematical perspective, I would say it is never used

Comment: I've never seen it used in symbolic logic either. You'd say not for-all and not not-for-all. @JPi is wrong about the equivalence, though. The exists not version is only equivalent if a non-empty domain is assumed, which it is not in all systems.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen it. Anyway:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\nforall}{%
  \ooalign{$\forall$\cr\hidewidth$\!/$\hidewidth\cr}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\nforall x\in A : F
\]

\[
\lnot\forall x\in A : F
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My humble proposal, as alternative, it is to use `cancel` package.
[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
${\cancel \forall} x\in A : F$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Others seem to be complicating this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\not \forall x \in A: F$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To add the picture you just drag and drop on the text box. I added it for you.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik : I generate PDFs and DVIs.  The input textbox rejects both.  The insert an image dialog does not accept PDFs or DVIs.  So I don't know what you are dragging and dropping, but it doesn't appear to be an output type I generate.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Yes, it only accepts image files. I convert the PDF to PNG using ImageMagick. If you use Linux, that's `convert -trim -density 300 file.pdf output.png` (`-trim` trims white space, `-density 300` is a good enough value for posting pictures here). But of course you can just take a screenshot of the PDF and post that as well.